# horizontally centering three h2's

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm struggling to horizontally center three `<h2>` elements

```css
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #FDF3E7;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #7E8F7C 3px;
}
```

```html
        <div id="container">
          <h2 class="header">Restaunt Name:</h2
          ><h2 class="header">Phone #:</h2
          ><h2 class="header">Star Rating:</h2>
        </div>
```

I tried removing the white space by reformatting the HTML. I also tried using [this site](http://howtocenterincss.com/). I can't get the third element to sit inside the container.

**Update:** I followed jcuenod's advice. This seems to have solved the block level question of horizontal centering, but looking at the styling, I am now wondering why the headers are matching with their results. Here is what they look like now.

[image]

Shouldn't the h2's occupy the entirety of the container, given that they are centered across a container with 100% width?

Comment: can you give a picture of what you really needde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Problem

The problem is that you have widths that fill the horizontal space (mostly; `33%`). But then your `<h2>` elements take up extra horizontal space because you add `padding` and `border`.

## The Solution

Use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) as follows:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

## Explanation

MDN explains the `border-box` setting for `box-sizing`:

> The width and height properties include the content, the padding and border, but not the margin.

MDN lists it as experimental but it has [very good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-box).

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
}
h2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #FDF3E7;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #7E8F7C 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2 class="header">Restaunt Name:</h2
  ><h2 class="header">Phone #:</h2
  ><h2 class="header">Star Rating:</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This comes very close to solving the problem perfectly. I am now wondering why the headers that we are styling here do not match up with the way ive formatted the response data that goes underneath.

Comment: It's not ideal to update your question like this because the answers become less relevant. I would say that this actually looks like a job for `display: table`.

Comment: upping the h2 widths to 33.33 seems to get it very close

Comment: If you want the `h2`s to fill the horizontal width, try using flex boxes - here's a simple mockup: https://jsfiddle.net/n1gL1msq/

Answer (score 0):

just use `display: block` for `<h2>`

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center;` to the `#container` element.

Because your `h2` elements are set to `inline-block` they don't occupy the full width of their container. That's why the centering is not working.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the question to respond to your answer.